# In starteam, how can I find out when a file was deleted, and by whom?

Tags: starteam

We have a small team running StarTeam. A constant source of frustration and problems is the handling of deleted files in StarTeam. It is obvious that Starteam keeps track of deleted files internally, but it does not seem to be possible to get any information about a file deletion.

So far, my only solution to find the timing of a delete is to perform a manual binary search using the 'compare' views. Is there any better way (the query for 'delete time' never seems to pick up any files).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Audit tab (just to the right of File, ChangeRequest, etc.) is probably your best bet if you're just looking for who deleted what and when.  The Audit tab also provides information about when items and folders were created, shared, or moved, as well as when View labels are attached/detached.  Whenever someone has files unexpectedly appear or disappear, I direct them to the Audit tab first.

There is a server-side configuration setting for the length of time the audit data is retained (30 days by default, I believe).  Since it is not retained forever, it isn't a good option for historical data.  The number of audits can be quite large in active views.

If you're looking for something more than that or older than your audit retention time, go with Bubbafat's suggestion of the SDK and getDeletedTime/getDeletedUserID.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing views (or rolling back a view to see the item again) is the only way I know how to do this in StarTeam without writing code.

If you are willing to write a little code the StarTeam API provides the Item.getDeletedTime and Item.getDeletedUserId methods (I believe these showed up in 2006).